# Probability for which die produced the 3?

Tags: probability

Sorry for the title but I don't know how to put it in just a few words in a title

I have 3 dice: a d4, a d6 and a d8, where dk denotes a k-sided die.

I take a random die and I get a 3 ! What's the probability that I chose the d8 ?

Should I apply conditional probability ? Or it's just a simple 1/3 ? Or a simple 1/8 ?

So it might be needed a conditional probability but how?

P(A|B) = (P(A) + P(B) - P(A U B))/P(B)

That's how it might be: 
A -> a "3" from any of the dice - P(A) = 1/4+1/6+1/8 = (6+4+3)/24 = 13/24
B -> the d8 has been chosen - P(B) = 1/3
A U B -> a "3" from the d8 has appeared - P(A U B) = 1/8

So is it...

(13/34 + 1/3 - 1/8)/ 1/3
?

Comment: Is this homework? Please add the self-study tag and read its Wiki. What thoughts do you have on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually it's curiosity with friends that it translated in a huge debate, and now I want to know. :) I tried to give an answer. It might be a conditional probability and might be A : get a 3 from all the dice (1/4+1/6+1/8) B: choose one of the 3 dice (1/3) and A U B : get a "3" from a d8 (1/3) . But.. I don't know.. it doesn't add up?

Comment: I’d use Bayes: $P(d8 \vert 3) = \dfrac{P(3\vert d8) P(d8)}{P(3)}$.

Comment: P(d8) is the probability to get a d8 ? So 1/3 and p(3|d8)?

Comment: That’s the probability of rolling a 3 given that you select the d8.

Comment: @Dave thank you ! Some of my friends are exulting as they won the final :D But there is something that still doesn't ring: P(3|d8)= 1/8,  P(d8)= 1/3, P(3)=13/24     so would be P(d8|3) = (1/8*1/3) / 13/24 = 0.0001335470085     isn't that too small ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104769/discussion-between-salvob-and-dave).

Comment: I attempted a more informative title. It's close enough to give the gist of the type of problem you're asking about

Comment: Initial intuition: imagine you roll each die 24 times. How many 3's will you expect on each die? Of those, how many do you expect to come from the 8?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your probability for A should be 13/72 because - hopefully it seems intuitively wrong to get more than half of the results be three, as implied by 13/24...

Secondly, the probability for the union means either occur, not both.

Thirdly, you should be calculating P(B|A). You condition on the three because this is what you observe. The probability for both is p(AB) = 1/3 × 1/8 = 1/24. This means the answer is P(B|A)=(1/24)/(13/72)=3/13